# upload a table in javafx to an excel sheet

Tags: java, javafx

I have been trying to find a way to upload a simple JavaFX table into an excel sheet. I can't find anywhere a simple solution to upload my JavaFX table into an excel sheet. I need a button that I will click and the current table will go to an excel sheet.

I have been trying a couple of tutorials and other things what I found on youtube and other sources. But everything I have been trying to find is kinda different than I need.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    TableView<Person> table;
    TextField nameInput, middlenameInput, backnameInput, adressInput, housenumberInput, zipcodeInput, residenceInput, dateofbirthInput, emailInput, phoneInput;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("thenewboston - JavaFX");

        TableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("name");
        nameColumn.setMinWidth(150);
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));


        TableColumn<Person, String> middlenameColumn = new TableColumn<>("t.v.");
        middlenameColumn.setMinWidth(75);
        middlenameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Middlename"));


        TableColumn<Person, String> backnameColumn = new TableColumn<>("last name");
        backnameColumn.setMinWidth(150);
        backnameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("backname"));


        TableColumn<Person, String> adressColumn = new TableColumn<>("adress");
        adressColumn.setMinWidth(150);
        adressColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("adress"));


        TableColumn<Person, String> housenumberColumn = new TableColumn<>("Nr");
        housenumberColumn.setMinWidth(30);
        housenumberColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("housenumber"));


        TableColumn<Person, String> zipcodeColumn = new TableColumn<>("zipcode");
        zipcodeColumn.setMinWidth(75);
        zipcodeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("zipcode"));


        TableColumn<Person, String> residenceColumn = new TableColumn<>("place");
        residenceColumn.setMinWidth(150);
        residenceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("residence"));


        TableColumn<Person, String> dateofbirthColumn = new TableColumn<>("date of birth");
        dateofbirthColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        dateofbirthColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateofbirth"));


        TableColumn<Person, String> emailColumn = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        emailColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        emailColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));


        TableColumn<Person, String> phoneColumn = new TableColumn<>("phone");
        phoneColumn.setMinWidth(150);
        phoneColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("phone"));


        nameInput = new TextField();
        nameInput.setPromptText("name");
        nameInput.setMinWidth(100);

        middlenameInput = new TextField();
        middlenameInput.setPromptText("t.v.");

        backnameInput = new TextField();
        backnameInput.setPromptText("lastName");


        adressInput = new TextField();
        adressInput.setPromptText("Adress");


        housenumberInput = new TextField();
        housenumberInput.setPromptText("nr");


        zipcodeInput = new TextField();
        zipcodeInput.setPromptText("zipcode");


        residenceInput = new TextField();
        residenceInput.setPromptText("place");


        dateofbirthInput = new TextField();
        dateofbirthInput.setPromptText("date of birth");


        emailInput = new TextField();
        emailInput.setPromptText("Email");


        phoneInput = new TextField();
        phoneInput.setPromptText("phone number");


        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(e -> addButtonClicked());

        Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");
        deleteButton.setOnAction(e -> deleteButtonClicked());


        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        hBox.setSpacing(10);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(nameInput, middlenameInput, backnameInput, adressInput, housenumberInput, zipcodeInput, residenceInput, dateofbirthInput, emailInput, phoneInput, addButton, deleteButton);

        table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(getPerson());
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, middlenameColumn, backnameColumn, adressColumn, housenumberColumn, zipcodeColumn, residenceColumn, dateofbirthColumn, emailColumn, phoneColumn);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(table, hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }


    //Add button clicked
    public void addButtonClicked(){
        Person product = new Person();
        product.setName(nameInput.getText());
        product.setMiddlename(middlenameInput.getText());
        product.setBackname(backnameInput.getText());
        product.setAdress(adressInput.getText());
        product.setHousenumber(housenumberInput.getText());
        product.setZipcode(zipcodeInput.getText());
        product.setResidence(residenceInput.getText());
        product.setDateofbirth(dateofbirthInput.getText());
        product.setEmail(emailInput.getText());
        product.setPhone(phoneInput.getText());


        table.getItems().add(product);
        nameInput.clear();
        middlenameInput.clear();
        backnameInput.clear();
        adressInput.clear();
        housenumberInput.clear();
        zipcodeInput.clear();
        residenceInput.clear();
        dateofbirthInput.clear();
        emailInput.clear();
        phoneInput.clear();

    }

    //Delete button clicked
    public void deleteButtonClicked(){
        ObservableList<Person> PersonSelected, allPersons;
        allPersons = table.getItems();
        PersonSelected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

        PersonSelected.forEach(allPersons::remove);
    }

    public ObservableList<Person> getPerson(){
        ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        persons.add(new Person("testName", "" , "lastName", "adressName", "nr", "zipcode", "place", "dateOfBirth", "email@gmail.com", "phoneNumber"));
        persons.add(new Person("testName", "" , "lastName", "adressName", "nr", "zipcode", "place", "dateOfBirth", "email@gmail.com", "phoneNumber"));
        persons.add(new Person("testName", "" , "lastName", "adressName", "nr", "zipcode", "place", "dateOfBirth", "email@gmail.com", "phoneNumber"));
        return persons;
    }

}
```

This is just a table with some common information. This I need to upload to an excel sheet by a button

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly paste the entire JavaFx table into Microsoft Excel sheet. You have to use Apache POI library to write into an Excel sheet. On click on JavaFx button, you have to take all the fields of your desired object model like Person object in your case and write to excel sheet using Apache POI library. Refer the link below.

https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Is it possible to just save it to a txt file?

Comment: Yes, you can save to a file by writing to a file from extracting the field values from Person object.